# Scrapy version of a Python requests.post

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I am doing a request to a specific endpoint adding some headers and a json using python requests. But since the architecture of the repository I'm coding in is based on scrapy, I would like to make the same request but translated to scrapy

#### My Json data

```
json_data = {
    'query': '',
    'page_size': 20,   # IMPORTANT FIELD
    'page_token': '0',   # IMPORTANT FIELD
    'sponsored_results_max': 2,    # IMPORTANT FIELD
    'locales': [       # IMPORTANT FIELD: We can use it to control the language
    'en', 'fr', 'de',
    ],
    'contract_types': [
    'alternating',
    'alternating',
    'berufsbegleitendes_studium',
    'job',
    'cdd',
    'cdi',
    'graduate_program',
    'vie',
    'part_time',
    'stage',
    'internship',
    'werkstudent',
    'thesis',
    'thesis',
    ],
    'school_ids': [
    '0',
    ],
    'curriculum_ids': None,
    'career_center_study_levels': [],
}
```

## The original request

#### Will give me the response I need

```
response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, json=json_data)
response.json()
```

#### The response I want (Briefly, because the original is bigger)

```
...{'parent_name': 'locale', 'name': 'es', 'count': 22}, {'parent_name': 'locale', 'name': 'it', 'count': 17}, {'parent_name': 'locale', 'name': 'fi', 'count': 7}, {'parent_name': 'locale', 'name': 'sv', 'count': 2}, {'parent_name': 'locale', 'name': 'pt', 'count': 1}, {'parent_name': 'school_ids', 'name': '0', 'count': 12982}...
```

## Scrapy alternatives that didin't gave me the expected response

#### First Fail

```
from scrapy.http import JsonRequest

j_response = JsonRequest(url=endpoint, headers=headers, data=json_data)
j_response.to_dict()
```

#### Second Fail

```
from scrapy import Request

sc_response = Request(method='POST', url=endpoint, headers=headers, body=json.dumps(json_data))
sc_response.to_dict()
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Are you getting exceptions?

Comment: This is one example of how you can send POST requests with scrapy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74015592/scrapy-is-not-scraping-the-whole-page-but-only-some-part-of-it/74018708#74018708 Let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `requests.post` or `requests.get` using the `requests` library, you are both creating a request object, and executing a fetch like procedure which acquires a response which is what is returned from those calls.

When you create a `scrapy.Request` it only creates the request instance and returns it.  The fetching portion is done by the crawler and the scrapy engine which receives the requests once they have been constructed by a `scrapy.Spider`.

So in both of your examples, the `sc_response` and `j_response` variables are still just request objects, that only include the information you provided to the constructor.  If you want scrapy to fetch the data from the URI, you will probably want to create a Spider to fetch them for you.

Additionally if you were working on a `scrapy.Response` object, they have the same `json()` method the the `request.Response` does, so you would want to use that in order to get the formatted json data.

For example:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'

    def start_requests(self):
        sc_request = Request(method='POST', url=endpoint, headers=headers, body=json.dumps(json_data))
        yield sc_request

    def parse(self, response):
        yield response.json()
```

Comment: Great! One more question, how could I execute it on a scrapy shell?
My intention is to first check if I'm getting the correct json response